# create a dict for items of two list once co occur in the same line in a file text

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary

If there are two lists of items, and the task is to create a dict of the items of the two lists (one items from list1 as key and one from list2 as value) once the two items co-occure in the same line of file text. Is there another way different from my following trial? Thanks

```
di =  {}
for line in file_text:
    for x in list1:
        for y in list2:
            if x in line and y in line:
                di[x]=y
```

Comment: `di = {x: y for x, y in zip(list1, list2) if x in line and y in line}`

Comment: Yes, there are other ways. Is there some reason you aren't satisfied with the way you've done it? Do you have a specific question about how it works?

Comment: @zondo, line is not defined

Comment: It should be `di = {x: y for line in file_text for x, y in zip(list1, list2) if x in line and y in line}`

Answer (score 0):

For best performance results, you should use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) along with Python's [dict comprehension syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
import itertools
di = {k: v for line in file_text for k, v in itertools.izip(list1, list2) if k in line and v in line}
```

A dict comprehension is a faster alternative to create your dictionary than nested `for` loops, and `itertools.izip` is more economical for memory consumption than a simple `zip` (especially for larger lists).